# How to fix this toggle function in d3?

Tags: d3.js, toggle

I have 2 problems here:

1/ These buttons (you can run the code snippet below) should reverse back to their former opacity at the second click but they don't ! Can someone explain me what's wrong with the code ?

2/ How do I reverse back to the `text` former color on the second click **without having to define that former color (again!) in the toggle function**. ?

Explanation: As you can see when running the following snippet, the `text` (1,2,3...) turns `white` at the first `click`. I'd like to set it back to its former color at the second click without having to write:

```
var newTextFill = active ? "white" : "**former_color**";
```

For instance, in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/JessicaFreaner/8fb0ac6c12aa1dab5f70) the author doesn't specify the `font-size` the legend should return to on a second click and yet you can see it shrinking back to its original size. How can I do the same thing here with the font colors ?

```js
 var name = ["123456789"];
 
 
 var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
               .range(["#00baff", "#0014fe", "#00dbaf", "#f4bf02", "#ffa600",                        "#ff0000", "#ff00c4", "#ee693e", "#99958f"]);
 
 
 var svg = d3.select("body")
             .append("svg")
             .attr("width", 300)
             .attr("height",300)
 
 var legende = svg.selectAll("bar")
                  .data(name)
                  .enter()
                  .append("g")
                  .attr("x",  0)
                  .attr("y", function (d,i) {return 12 + i * 20})

    legende.append("text")
           .text(function(d,i) { return name[i]})
           .attr("class", "legtext")
           .style("font-family", "helvetica")
           .style("fill-opacity", 0.8)
           .attr("x",  4)
           .attr("y", function (d,i) {return 12 + i * 20})
           .style("font-size", 10)
           .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i)})
           .style("text-decoration", "none")
           .style("opacity", 1);

    legende.append("rect")
           .attr("class", "recta")
           .attr("x",  2)
           .attr("y", function (d,i) {return 1 + i * 20})
           .attr("width", 65)
           .attr("height", 15)
           .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i)})
           .style("opacity", 0.09);

    legende.append("rect")
           .attr("class", "rectastroke")
           .attr("id", function(d,i) {return "str" + i})
           .attr("x",  2)
           .attr("y", function (d,i) {return 1 + i * 20})
           .attr("width", 65)
           .attr("height", 15)
           .style("stroke", function(d,i) { return color(i)})
           .style("stroke-width", 0.5) 
           .style("fill", "none")
           .attr("display", "none");
           
           
           
    legende.on("click", function (d,i) 
               {var active = d.active ? false : true;
                var newOpacity = active ? 1 : 0.1;
                var newTextFill = active ? "white" : "blue";
               
               d3.select(this)
                 .select("rect")
                 .style("opacity", newOpacity)
                 
                 
               d3.select(this)
                 .select("text")
                 .style("fill", newTextFill)
                 .raise()
                 
               d.active = active  });  
           
           
           
           
    legende.on("mouseover", function(d, i)      
        {d3.select(this).selectAll(".rectastroke").attr("display", "true")});
        
    legende.on("mouseout", function(d, i)      
        {d3.select(this).selectAll(".rectastroke").attr("display", "none")});
```

```css
body {font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
          font-size: 11px;
          font-weight: 300;
          fill: #242424;
          text-align: center;
          cursor: default;}
          
     .legende {cursor: pointer;}
     .recta {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

   

<body>
     <div class="colored buttons"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the bl.ocks you linked she is, in fact, specifying the font size the legend will return to on a second click... in the CSS.

What's happening is that if `active` is false, the setter will return `undefined`...

```
d3.select(this)
    .style("font-size", function() {
        if (active) {return "25px"}
    })
```

... and the UA will set the style based on the CSS.

You can do the same thing to your rectangles without specifying any `newOpacity`:

```
d3.select(this)
    .select("rect")
    .style("opacity", function() {
        if (active) return 1;
    })
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = "123456789".split("").map(function(d) {
  return {
    value: d
  }
});

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#00baff", "#0014fe", "#00dbaf", "#f4bf02", "#ffa600", "#ff0000", "#ff00c4", "#ee693e", "#99958f"]);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 300)

var legende = svg.selectAll("bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return 12 + i * 20
  })

legende.append("text")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return d.value
  })
  .attr("class", "legtext")
  .style("font-family", "helvetica")
  .style("fill-opacity", 0.8)
  .attr("x", 4)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return 12 + i * 20
  })
  .style("font-size", 10)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i)
  })
  .style("text-decoration", "none")
  .style("opacity", 1);

legende.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "recta")
  .attr("x", 2)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return 1 + i * 20
  })
  .attr("width", 65)
  .attr("height", 15)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i)
  });

legende.on("click", function(d, i) {
  var active = d.active ? false : true;

  d3.select(this)
    .select("rect")
    .style("opacity", function() {
      if (active) return 1;
    })

  d3.select(this)
    .select("text")
    .style("fill", function(e, j) {
      if (active) {
        return "white";
      } else {
        return color(i)
      }
    })
    .raise()

  d.active = active
});
```

```css
.legende {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.recta {
  opacity: 0.1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

For the text color, however, since you are not specifying it in the CSS, you'll have to use a normal `if...else` code.

Comment: I get it now, thank you so much for the comprehensive explanation @GerardoFurtado !